# How to set an error messages in block while getting error in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

[image]

[image]

I am getting errors from script,but those errors need to put in block as seen in below image.can anybody help me on this.......

Comment: use `apex:pagemessage` in your code

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<apex:pageMessages />` tag to show these error on Page.

Use below code to set these messages from controller.

```
ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Please fill required fields.');
ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Deepak, but i used that apex:messages Code.when i am using that code, one after one showing error. i have 10 fields if 5 fields is empty outof 10,need to show 5 errors when save button clicks.can you help me on this.....

Comment: Use <apex:pageMessages  escape="true" /> and from your controller method which you're executing on Save Button, write below code.
String error = '';
if(fieldOne == null)
  error += fieldOne +'is required. <br/> ' ;
if(fieldTwo == null)
  error += fieldTwo +'is required  <br/> '  ;
... repeat this process for all fields 
ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, error);
ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);